# Search a file in a directory using wildcards

Tags: java, file-search

I need to check if some files exist in a directory using Java but the file name have a pattern. For example the file name is recap_data_03082017.txt and the numbers at the end are always changing. Is there a way to perform a search using a wildcard like recap_data_*.csv

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: did you try string.contains()?

Comment: org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.wildcardMatching(fileName,wildCard) but it's too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you could try the following,

```
 try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/your/path/"), 1)) {
            return paths
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .anyMatch(f -> {
                        final String fileName = f.getFileName().toString();
                        return fileName.startsWith("ecap_data_") && fileName.endsWith(".csv");
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This works fine but I couldn't manage how to return true or false as a return statement for my method because I found it's a very complicated syntax

Comment: Sorry just realized you want to check if file with pattern exists

Comment: It's Ok ;) it resolved 90% of the problem for me :) Thank you

Comment: I edited the answer, it returns a boolean now